# Mongodb Aggregate Filter Array Of Array Of Array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

We would like to filter SKU's List which has `verificationData` data and  `differenceInStock` difference greater than or Less than 0

Here is an example Data Set.

```
[
    {
        "_id": "636e0beaa13ef73324e613f0",
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "inventory": 132,
        "parentCategory": [
            "Salt"
        ],
        "title": "Aashirvaad MRP: 28Rs Salt 27 kg Bopp Bag (Set of 1 kg x 27)",
        "createdAt": "2022-11-11T08:46:34.950Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-11-24T17:43:27.361Z",
        "__v": 3,
    
        "verificationData": [
            {
                "_id": "637c57ebbe783a9a138fc2d3",
                "verificationDate": "2022-11-22T05:02:35.155Z",
                "items": {
                    "listingId": "636e0beaa13ef73324e613f0",
                    "phyiscalVerification": [
                        {
                            "verifiedBy": "634534e72ef6462fcb681a39",
                            "closingStock": 178,
                            "phyiscalStock": 178,
                            "differenceInStock": 0,
                            "verifiedAt": "2022-11-22T10:19:38.388Z",
                            "_id": "637ca23abe783a9a1394f402"
                        }
                    ],
                    "_id": "637ca23abe783a9a1394f401"
                },
                "yearMonthDayUTC": "2022-11-22"
            },
            {
                "_id": "637d9b65be783a9a13998726",
                "verificationDate": "2022-11-23T04:02:45.804Z",
                "items": {
                    "listingId": "636e0beaa13ef73324e613f0",
                    "phyiscalVerification": [
                        {
                            "verifiedBy": "634534e72ef6462fcb681a39",
                            "closingStock": 161,
                            "phyiscalStock": 167,
                            "differenceInStock": 6,
                            "verifiedAt": "2022-11-23T09:52:36.815Z",
                            "_id": "637ded64be783a9a13a29d55"
                        }
                    ],
                    "_id": "637ded64be783a9a13a29d54"
                },
                "yearMonthDayUTC": "2022-11-23"
            },
            {
                "_id": "637f0254be783a9a13a94354",
                "verificationDate": "2022-11-24T05:34:12.995Z",
                "items": {
                    "listingId": "636e0beaa13ef73324e613f0",
                    "phyiscalVerification": [
                        {
                            "verifiedBy": "634534e72ef6462fcb681a39",
                            "closingStock": 144,
                            "phyiscalStock": 146,
                            "differenceInStock": 2,
                            "verifiedAt": "2022-11-24T12:02:28.123Z",
                            "_id": "637f5d54be783a9a13b1039a"
                        }
                    ],
                    "_id": "637f5d54be783a9a13b10399"
                },
                "yearMonthDayUTC": "2022-11-24"
            },
            {
                "_id": "2022-11-25",
                "yearMonthDayUTC": "2022-11-25",
                "items": null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "62b5c39062ddb963fc64c42d",
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "inventory": 10,
        "parentCategory": [
            "Salt"
        ],
        "finalMeasurementUnit": "kg",
        "finalMeasure": "1 kg",
        "title": "Marvella Citric Acid Lemon Salt 1 kg Pouch (Set of 500 gm x 2)",
        "createdAt": "2022-06-24T14:00:49.052Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-11-21T11:04:21.643Z",
        "__v": 2,
        "verificationData": [
            {
                "_id": "2022-11-22",
                "yearMonthDayUTC": "2022-11-22",
                "items": null
            },
            {
                "_id": "2022-11-23",
                "yearMonthDayUTC": "2022-11-23",
                "items": null
            },
            {
                "_id": "2022-11-24",
                "yearMonthDayUTC": "2022-11-24",
                "items": null
            },
            {
                "_id": "2022-11-25",
                "yearMonthDayUTC": "2022-11-25",
                "items": null
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This could have array of 100+ SKU's

Our Aggregate Functions is as Follows

```
let reqData = await userListing.aggregate([
        {
          $match: {
            warehouseId: { $eq: ObjectId(warehouseId) },
            parentCategory: { $in: catList },
            isWarehouseListing: { $eq: true },
            isBlocked: { $ne: true },
            isArchived: { $ne: true },
          },
        },
        { $sort: { whAddedAt: -1 } },   
        
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "listingstockverifications",
            let: { listId: "$_id" },
            pipeline: [
              {
                $match: {
                  verificationDate: {
                    $gte: newFromDate,
                    $lt: newToDate,
                  },
                },
              },
              {
                $project: {
                  verificationDate: 1,
                  items: {
                    $filter: {
                      input: "$items",
                      cond: {
                        $and: [
                          /* {
                            "$$this.phyiscalVerification": {
                              $filter: {
                                input: "$$this.phyiscalVerification",
                                as: "psitem",
                                cond: { $gt: [ "$$psitem.differenceInStock", 0 ] },
                              },
                            },
                          }, */
                          {
                            $eq: ["$$this.listingId", "$$listId"],
                          },
                        ],
                      },
                    },
                  },
                  yearMonthDayUTC: {
                    $dateToString: {
                      format: "%Y-%m-%d",
                      date: "$verificationDate",
                    },
                  },
                },
              },
              { $unwind: "$items" },
            ],
            as: "stockVerification",
          },
        },
        {
          $addFields: {
            verificationData: {
              $map: {
                input: dummyArray,
                as: "date",
                in: {
                  $let: {
                    vars: {
                      dateIndex: {
                        $indexOfArray: [
                          "$stockVerification.yearMonthDayUTC",
                          "$$date",
                        ],
                      },
                    },
                    in: {
                      $cond: {
                        if: { $ne: ["$$dateIndex", -1] },
                        then: {
                          $arrayElemAt: ["$stockVerification", "$$dateIndex"],
                        },
                        else: {
                          _id: "$$date",
                          yearMonthDayUTC: "$$date",
                          items: null,
                        },
                      },
                    },
                  },
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
        {
          $project: {
            stockVerification: 0,
          },
        },
      ]);
```

At Last now we would like to filter the SKU List the which has following Data

`verificationData[].items.phyiscalVerification[].differenceInStock is Greater than or Less than 0`

Expected Output in the following Exmaple would be 1st SKUs
as 2nd SKU does not have any Item Data
and even if in 3rd SKU if we got Item Data but should match the following condition

`verificationData[].items.phyiscalVerification[].differenceInStock is Greater than or Less than 0`

Thank you for taking your time to read and support.

Comment: can you show the expected result in JSON format from your example document?

Answer (score 0):

You can add these two following stages to your aggregation, The idea is simple - just filter out all subdocuments that do not match the condition.

Because of the nested structure it's just not the sexiest of pipelines but it will suffice.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          "verificationData.items.phyiscalVerification.differenceInStock": {
            $gt: 0
          }
        },
        {
          "verificationData.items.phyiscalVerification.differenceInStock": {
            $lt: 0
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      verificationData: {
        $filter: {
          input: {
            $map: {
              input: {
                $filter: {
                  input: "$verificationData",
                  as: "verification",
                  cond: {
                    $ne: [
                      "$$verification.items",
                      null
                    ]
                  }
                }
              },
              as: "top",
              in: {
                $mergeObjects: [
                  "$$top",
                  {
                    "items": {
                      "$mergeObjects": [
                        "$$top.items",
                        {
                          phyiscalVerification: {
                            $filter: {
                              input: "$$top.items.phyiscalVerification",
                              as: "pshycical",
                              cond: {
                                $ne: [
                                  "$$pshycical.differenceInStock",
                                  0
                                ]
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          cond: {
            $gt: [
              {
                $size: "$$this.items.phyiscalVerification"
              },
              0
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/935pKy417CL)

Comment: sir no no
here im getting missed with one date
if you could actually analize by $MAP data - its DummyArray which is
 [ '2022-11-25', '2022-11-26', '2022-11-27' ]